# MySQL Error #1064 on this INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging, mysql-error-1064

Not sure what's wrong, just running this in PHP MyAdmin right now. Does anything pop out to you? Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO order (CustomerID, BillAddr, ShipAddr, Date, Total)   
VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', '2012-07-02', 22)
```

Error:

> MySQL said: #1064

Structure of `order` table:

```
FIELD                TYPE  
OrderID         int(11) auto increment  
CustomerID      varchar(50)  
BillAddr        varchar(200)  
ShipAddr        varchar(200)  
Date            date  
Total           double
```

(I leave the OrderID out of the INSERT as it is an auto increment)

**EDIT**
Same error with this syntax:

```
SQL query:

INSERT INTO 'order'( CustomerID, BillAddr, ShipAddr, 'Date', Total )
VALUES (
'test', 'test', 'test', '2012-07-02', 22
)
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 -
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word `Date` is a keyword.  Try it like this:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (CustomerID, BillAddr, ShipAddr, `Date`, Total)   
VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', '2012-07-02', 22)
```

ETA: And `order` is also a keyword :)

Comment: single quotes around the key words.... still getting 1064? please see the edit to the question.

Comment: @greg, not single-quotes but back-ticks. Single-quotes are for strings.

Comment: @greg - You can also use double quotes in ANSI mode instead of backticks.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: the back ticks did it, I have never used those in my life, not sure if i should admit that. OK thanks, I will rememberthe double quotes too!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got bitten on the `group` keyword.